# Error when running browse in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, foursquare

When I run my app it loads fine but when I click on 'Browse' in AppEngine to see if my connected app is loading I get the following:

```
    main.py, line 54
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'name': CONFIG['site_name']}
                                                                              ^

    IndentationError: unindent does not match outer indentation level
    INFO server.py:585] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have fixed this line of code and no matter what I do it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried closing the parenthesis? `self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'name': CONFIG['site_name']}))`

Comment: Yes, I have. That's how I had it originally coded and it kept giving me the error with the ^ underneath with what is wrong. I don't know what it is. I've changed it several times with the suggestion with the ^ and each time I do I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mixed indentations of tabs and spaces. If so, try converting all tabs to spaces and reindent the whole code.

Check if python versions GAE/local are the same?

If nothing helps try commenting everything out and uncomment incrementally part by part until you locate real location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not necessarily related to line 54.  You have to make sure your `self.response.out.write('...')` is properly nested within the `get()` function above it.  As was already mentioned, you shouldn't mix tabs and spaces.  A good python text editor will avoid this problem altogether.  your code should look something like this...

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        path = '/path/to/template'
        CONFIG = {'site_name': 'Google'}
        my_html = template.render(path, {'name': CONFIG['site_name']})
        self.response.out.write(my_html)
```